# Generating bimodal distributions

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, descriptive-statistics

I have a problem where I have 5 examples of truncated bimodal distributions between different ranges of (-1.0, +1.0), (-0.18, +0.18), (-0.12, +0.12) and (-0.15, +0.15). The example distributions can be viewed [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgnkR.jpg).

Please note that for all of the given example bimodal distributions, ***there is no zero values*** within the given distribution! The data distributions have values ranging between the given ranges EXCEPT of ZERO!

I am trying to create a sampling technique which can create random samples by obeying the given bimodal samples in the examples. The samples to be drawn can be of any size/shape/dimension such as 784, 5000, etc.

Any ideas how I can create such truncated bimodal data distributions between intervals 'a' and 'b' or [a, b] (both points are included)!

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like the rejection rate wouldn't be too bad if you just did rejection sampling with a uniform distribution?

Comment: @joriki can you point to some resources?

Comment: I can't, unfortunately, I usually learn such things from Wikipedia. If you don't understand that article, you can always ask a question about it here.

Comment: Apart from the maximum and minimum and the sample sizes, what else do you know about the distributions? If you have stretched beta distributions then you could use an expression such as `rbeta(n, shape1, shape2)*(b-a)+a` where `n` is the sample size, `a` is the minimum,  `b` is the maximum.  This will be bimodal at the extremes if `shape1` and `shape2` are between $0$ and $1$, and symmetric if they are equal to each other